# Filtering specific data out of an api in python?

Tags: python, list, api, dictionary, types

I try to "filter" out some specific data out of the list I get from an api request of a plane tracking website.

```
import json, urllib.request
url = "https://ktrax.kisstech.ch/backend/tracking?db=aviation&sw_lat=47.32453673528682&sw_lon=7.87192272434162&ne_lat=47.35361867238683&ne_lon=7.899774782752265&max_results=300&max_age=1960&apikey=TRACK-c47d70c58861af97"

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

data = json.load(response)['targets']
print(data)

plane = data.index('icao:4B4BAB')
print(plane)
```

As you can see, I already make use of the json data being a dictionary and sorting the list 'targets'. This then yields the following output (type = list).

```
[['icao:4B51E1', 1, '2020-05-24T13:18:53Z', 0, 47.349683, 7.8754167, 1067, 0, 3, 28, 47, -0.6, 15, 0, 1, 0, 'LSPO', ['HB-3386', 'O7', '-', '-'], 100, 0, 0], ['icao:4B4BF5', 1, '2020-05-24T13:18:53Z', 0, 47.3497, 7.87945, 1593, 0, 1, 29, 248, 0.9, -0.9, 0, 1, 0, 'LSPO', ['HB-1870', 'FC', '-', '-'], 100, 0, 0], ['icao:4B512D', 1, '2020-05-24T13:18:53Z', 0, 47.349617, 7.87505, 990.6, 0, 2, 29, 79, -1.1, 11, 0, 1, 0, 'LSPO', ['HB-3206', 'O6', '-', '-'], 100, 0, 0], ['icao:4B5105', 1, '2020-05-24T13:18:48Z', 5, 47.343817, 7.88915, 459, 0, 2, 0, 1800, 0.1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 'LSPO', ['HB-3166', 'O2', '-', '-'], 100, 0, 0], ['icao:4B4AA8', 1, '2020-05-24T13:18:35Z', 19, 47.343867, 7.8887167, 465.7, 0, 1, 0, 1800, 0.1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 'LSPO', ['HB-1537', 'W', '-', '-'], 100, 0, 0], ['icao:4B51B4', 1, '2020-05-24T13:18:51Z', 2, 47.3437, 7.8885, 464.8, 0, 2, 0, 1800, -0.097, 0, 0, 1, 0, 'LSPO', ['HB-3341', 'AK', '-', '-'], 100, 0, 0], ['icao:4B4BAB', 1, '2020-05-24T13:18:47Z', 6, 47.344083, 7.8883, 460.9, 0, 2, 0, 1800, -0.097, 0, 0, 1, 0, 'LSPO', ['HB-1796', '-', '-', '-'], 100, 0, 0], ['flarm:DD810E', 1, '2020-05-24T13:18:47Z', 6, 47.344017, 7.8890333, 460.9, 0, 3, 0, 1800, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'LSPO', ['-', '-', '-', '-'], 100, 0, 0], ['icao:4B4ADC', 1, '2020-05-24T13:18:54Z', 0, 47.338767, 7.8773333, 814.7, 0, 2, 24, 309, 0.2, 6.3, 0, 1, 0, 'LSPO', ['HB-1589', '-', '-', '-'], 100, 0, 0]]
```

Now, I want filter out only specific entries for icao:... and then read the the eleventh element of specific icao codes(when counting like python) out of the list which indicates the altitude difference of the plane.

Example: `['icao:4B51E1', '-0.6', 'icao:4B51B4', '-0.097']`

Now my problem is, that such an entry: `['icao:4B4BAB', 1, '2020-05-24T13:18:47Z', 6, 47.344083, 7.8883, 460.9, 0, 2, 0, 1800, -0.097, 0, 0, 1, 0, 'LSPO', ['HB-1796', '-', '-', '-'], 100, 0, 0]` marks one single list entry. How can I now, first of all, search the entire list for the specific icao:4B4BAB ? Using the dicitonary functions to sort them out right after sorting for 'targets' doesn't work due to a Type Error and if I try finding the index of it, it gives me a Value Error and says that the element isn't part of the list (But it is obviously in there).

Furthermore, how can I print the code and the eleventh element of the entry?

Looking forward to your answers

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the `data` list and check the first element of each list in data.

```
for plane in data:
    if plane[0] == 'icao:4B4BAB':
        print(plane[0], plane[11])
```

The `ValueError` is because the icao code is in fact not an entry in the `data` list but is in the first element of the `data` list which is in turn another list.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will give this a try. What I've tried so far (and it works) is the following: 

`for i in range(0,len(data)):
    newlist.append(data[i][17][0])
    newlist.append(data[i][11])
print(newlist)`

The result is the following:

`['HB-1537', 0.1, 'HB-3205', -0.097, 'HB-1796', -0.6]`

The problem which now comes up is that it seems to be difficult to search a list for a combination of letters and integers. The following always gives me a Value Error and says that it isn't part of the list:

`Planes=['HB-1796']
newlist.index(Planes)`

Comment: With that `newlist` you should not do `planes=['..']` but `planes = '..'`. That is why you're getting ValueError now. If you just want to select a few then I would get that out of the way first and then worry about formatting the data later. So first do something like `newdata = [entry for entry in data if entry[0] == 'icao:...']` or `[entry for entry in data if entry[17][0] == 'HB-1796']` or even `[entry for entry in data if entry[17][0] in Planes]`.